# How to define default values for arguments in an sbt input task?

Tags: scala, command-line, sbt

I want to define a task in sbt to flush all of my redis keys. It currently looks like this:

```
lazy val flushRedis = inputKey[Unit]("Flush redis")
flushRedis := {
  val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
  s"redis-cli -h ${args(0)} -p ${args(1)} flushall" !
}
```

And `sbt 'flushRedis host port'` works perfectly fine.

However, what I would like to achieve is to have the host and port optional, and fill in with default values for the arguments that were not provided.

For example I am using flyway to migrate my remote database with a command like this:

```
sbt flywayMigrate -Dflyway.url=... -Dflyway.user=... -Dflyway.password=...
```

And there are are default values defined for the url and user in build.sbt like this:

```
flywayUrl := "url"
flywayUser := "user"
```

Is it possible to accomplish something similar with my custom task? I don't mind making significant changes, as long as I get the effect.